# Add an extra border on the top of the div

Tags: html, css

I want to add **an extra border on the top** of the .menu div.
Firstly i added top and bottom border using box-shadow. and then another regular border using 
border-bottom:
border-left:
border-right:

now i want to add a border next the top white border(created by box-shadow) same as the regular border just like [this](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/835/slgz.jpg).

[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189718598/now/index.html) is the link for my current progress

Comment: do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/dw4YR/

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dw4YR/1/)

You don't need to specify `border-top`, `border-bottom`, `border-right`, `border-left`. Just simply specify like this `border:1px solid #b8b7b7;`. You are missing `border-top` in your css

```
.menu_area
    {
    width:960px;margin:0 auto;height:42px;box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 -3px #FFFFFF, 0 4px 2px -2px#ededed;
    border:1px solid #b8b7b7;
    }
```

Comment: i have tried this earlier . Here the problem is that i want 
the top white border before the border:1px solid #b8b7b7. other three side is ok. here is the [image](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/835/slgz.jpg) view what i want to do. plz zoom the image for better understanding.

Comment: like this? using gold color http://jsfiddle.net/dw4YR/6/ & this is for you using white color http://jsfiddle.net/dw4YR/7/..

Answer (score 0):

Use css `outline` for this.

Check This- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/Vm9aM/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p 
{
border:1px solid red;
outline:green solid thick;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Here you go</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Beginner said, you don't need to specify the side (top, right, left, bottom) when you want to apply the effect to all sides, just **boder: [styles];** it's enough in your css.